# Date and Time MySQL Statement

Tags: mysql

I have two fields, "cont_time_published" and "cont_date_published" that I want to use to filter results in a listing of records.

```
select *
from news
WHERE cont_date_published < CURDATE() AND cont_time_published < CURTIME()
```

I am trying to achieve listing that only shows records that the publish time and publish date is in the past. So that it would filter a record that has today's date but the time is still in the future.

Results are wrong when the date is today and the time is future.

cont_date_published is "DATE" only field and cont_time_published is "TIME" Field.

Comment: If it's not too late, just merge both columns into one of type DATETIME and save yourself all the hassle.

Comment: Álvaro González my framework does not allow for time and date to be one field due to the date and time pickers.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get the records published in the past (today in the past hours or before) try:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM news  
  WHERE cont_date_published < CURDATE() 
  OR (cont_date_published = CURDATE() AND cont_time_published < CURTIME());
```

sorry my mistake, forgot the `OR`

Comment: @Cavemanharris - this answer will give only row < CURTIME() from each day, not only today. is this what you want ?

Comment: I only used the section after OR and it works perfectly thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM news
WHERE (cont_date_published < CURDATE() ) AND ( cont_time_published < CURTIME() ) 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can CAST to an actual date:

```
WHERE CAST(CONCAT(cont_date_published, ' ', cont_time_published) AS DATETIME)<NOW()
```

... but this will possibly prevent query optimiser from using indexes (if any). An alternative would be:

```
WHERE cont_date_published<CURDATE() OR
    (cont_date_published=CURDATE() AND cont_time_published<CURTIME())
```

Of course, all this extra work could be easily avoided with a proper database design that makes use of a single DATETIME column:

```
WHERE cont_published<NOW()
```

Comment: great, the first one that see thism - +1

Comment: Álvaro González - after some testing the first option i chose did not work. your solution here worked well. the ..Cast(Concat.. option

Answer (score 0):

```
   select * from news WHERE cont_date_published < CURDATE()
```

This will be enough to get the records that are Published in the Past.